# Jquery AJAX relative paths concatenated with current url

Tags: html, ajax, django

I am having the following AJAX request to some location mentioned in the URL field. when I try to send this request, It concatenates the current URL (from browser) and append this AJAX URL with it and my PUT request fails all the time.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: 'qres/pfolio/v1/'+portfolio_id+'/',
  data: put_data,
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  },
});
```

if the current page url from browser it "http://localhost:8000/portfolio/2/" then the ajax call goes to "http://localhost:8000/portfolio/2/qres/pfolio/v1/2/"

How can I correct the relative url so that It goes to "http://localhost:8000/qres/pfolio/v1/2/"

Comment: Make it absolute:  `url: '/qres/pfolio/v1/'+portfolio_id+'/'`. Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change:

```
url: 'qres/pfolio/v1/'+portfolio_id+'/',
```

to:

```
url: '/qres/pfolio/v1/'+portfolio_id+'/',
```